# Ninject - basic use

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a class with `Ninject`

but I don't know Ninject so hight.

Why always must type this method?

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(
  System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, 
  System.Type controllerType)
{
  return controllerType == null 
    ? null 
    : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: The real Iron Man would say something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Ninject is an [IOC (Inversion of Control)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) package.

The code you are always typing, asks the Ninject container to find the controller for the specified type.

Comment: It bears mentioning that while Ninject is an IOC, using `.Get` is literally the opposite of IOC -- it's using Ninject as a service locator.  (though presumably this is a low-level one-time-thing place where this is happening to bootstrap the injection)